# Finding limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}$

Tags: limits

I don't know how to solve the following:

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence with property $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{x_n}{n}|<\infty$. Find a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}$.

Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [More general result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793540/dirichlet-series)

Comment: Does $x$ have a range of values it can take on? Check out the law of large numbers as well